# Degree one branched cover is a homeomorphism

Tags: riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces, branch-points

Suppose that $f:X \to Y$ is a branched cover of Riemann surfaces and a covering map of degree one outside of the ramification points. Then is $f$ a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $f$ is an homeomorphism since the the cardinal of the fibre of a branched point is inferior to the degree. I assume of course that the surfaces are closed.